# Guide how to create own "Media Container Format" ( File Extension) ? Encoding/Decoding

Tags: java, php, c++, encoding, media

I am trying to build my own **Media Container Format**.

Which should for example contain **.mp3 and .png´s**.

Till now I was working around with PHP and Java and managed to create .wav files from raw byte arrays.
Still I am lacking deeper knowledge about this field.

**Questions:**

- How do I approach this best?
- What encoding algorithmns should I use ?
- Is it necessary to convert existing files like .mp3 to raw data
  format in order to create the media container and its´ offsets?

I would be very thankful if someone could tell me more about this.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hold multiple files I would use a standard archive like [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip).

Comment: Hi, yes I thought about that. I was trying to create a proprietary extension. That would be the easiest.

Comment: It appears to be the obvious and most portable choice. ;)

Comment: Haha If I won´t find a solution to this, your answer gets accepted :D